# Beginners materials for web security

Tags: appsec, web-application, professional-education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources to learn about security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/266/resources-to-learn-about-security)

What materials can I study to learn web development security. I'm a web developer, I use ASP.NET, Java, PHP, and JavaScript. I want to learn how to build strong and robust web sites that are not vulnerable. I want to protect my backend database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I happen to think the following two resources provide an outstanding introduction to web security for developers:

- [An excellent overview for developers](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/14/web-security-primer-are-you-part-of-the-problem/) -- this should be a must-read for every programmer doing web development.
- [Web security tutorials at Google Code University](https://code.google.com/edu/security/index.html)

@Nam's answer links to a number of other good resources.  And a search on "web security" on this site will reveal many additional resources, e.g.,

- [If you could have only one book on web security, what would it be?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/419/971)
- [Web Security Cheatsheet / ToDo list](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2985/971)
- [What are the most important security checks for new web applications?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/387/971)
- [Security attacks on PHP web applications](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1906/971)
- [What tools are available to assess the security of a web application?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/32/971)

If you read through those pages, you'll find tons of great resources referenced in the answers there.

Also, I encourage you to take a look at Stanford's [CS 241](https://courseware.stanford.edu/pg/courses/81544/cs241-spring-2010) and [CS 142](http://crypto.stanford.edu/cs142/) courses on secure web programming.  The courses are excellent and prepared by world experts in the subject, and the course material is available online.  You'll learn a lot by going through the course on your own.  A similar course may be offered [over the summer](http://scpd.stanford.edu/search/publicCourseSearchDetails.do?method=load&courseId=1284862) for a relatively affordable price.  (I have no connection or affiliation with Stanford.)

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend these OWASP materials:

Application Security Verification Project at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project

Development Guide at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_Table_of_Contents

Testing Guide at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v3_Table_of_Contents

and Code Review Guide at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Code_Review_Guide_Table_of_Contents